# how is this done using AWK / SED : Insert lines regularly and then prepend the rest of the lines for every Nth Line

Tags: loops, sed, awk, insert, append

How is this done using AWK / SED. I tired arrays but apparently deleting a range isn't that easy in ksh arrays
Input file is like this

```
f1
f2
f3
f4
f5
f6
f7
f8
f9
f10
```

I need to start from the beginning of file and loop through N times.Lets keep N as 3. So create directory  after every 3 files .Output file looks like this

```
   mkdir dir_1
   mv f1 dir_1
   mv f2 dir_1
   mv f3 dir_1
   echo "command -o option tralla.lalla /path/dir_1" >> logfile  
   mkdir dir_2
   mv f3 dir_2
   mv f4 dir_2
   mv f6 dir_2
   echo "command -o option tralla.lalla /path/dir_2" >> logfile  
   mkdir dir_3
   mv f7 dir_3
   mv f8 dir_3
   mv f9 dir_3
   echo "command -o option tralla.lalla /path/dir_3" >> logfile  

   mkdir dir_4
   mv f10 dir_4

   #since there are only 10 files.dir_4 takes in whatever remains off that list 
   echo "command -o option tralla.lalla /path/dir_4" >> logfile
```

I tried arrays but the results are totally wonky

```
    th=$1
ar=('f1' 'f2' 'f3' 'f4' 'f5' 'f6')

for ((i=1; i<=$th; i++)); do

<stuff>
if [ "$i" -eq "$th" ]

then
# if its the last iteration of the loop.Whatever remains in the array - spit that out 
echo " `echo ${ar[*]}`"    >> somefile 

# it its anything short of the last iteration.Read N elements of the array at a time 
# and then delete them 
else
echo " `echo ${ar[*]:0:$N}`  " >> somefile 
     for ((x=0; x<=$N; x++)) ; do
     unset ar[$x]
     done

fi
```

I think it can be better achieved using the veteran file manipulators SED and AWK. **All 
"SED" uctive   and "AWK" ward people are cordially invited.**

Thanks. I corrected it
So at the end of the command a file is generated like the one above ( exactly like above ). I will then execute it later on . Its a command file - not executed but when it will be . It will move the directories and generate the commands for the command .

@Fedorqui and Glen
To make my last comment readable.
Thanks. Using the -v hint . This is the final command that worked. Yep you were right about n being var

```
awk -v n=$nn 'NR%n == 1 {print "mkdir dir_"++i}
{print "mv", $1, "dir_"i} NR%n==0
{print "echo \"command -o option tralla.lalla /path/dir_"NR/n "\" >> logfile" }END
{print "echo \"command -o option tralla.lalla /path/dir_"i"\" >> logfile"}' file
```

Comment: After `mv f10 dir_3` it is `command  dir_3` or `command  dir_4`?

Comment: TY SO SO MUCH. Yes you are right about the last command. I edited the post

Comment: actually the command itself contains the directory name. ` echo "command -o option tralla.lala /path/$directoryname" > log ` everything from echo to log . How can I get that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this can make it:

```
awk 'NR%3 == 1 {print "mkdir dir_"++i}
     {print "mv", $1, "dir_"i}
     NR%3==0{print "command dir_"NR/3}
     END{print "echo \"command -o option tralla.lalla /path/dir_"i"\" >> logfile"}' file
```

In case the `3` is something to be variable, you can populate it with `-v` as follows:

```
awk -v n=3 'NR%n == 1 ...
            {print "mv", $1, "dir_"i}
            NR%n==0{print "command dir_"NR/n}
            END {} .... ' file
```

#### Explanation

Basically it plays with `NR`, which stands for number of record (number of line in this case).

- `NR%3 == 1` stands for lines whose number of line is 3k + 1.
- `NR%3 == 0` stands for lines whose number of line is 3k, that is, multiple of `3`.
- `END{print "echo \"command -o option tralla.lalla /path/dir_"i"\" >> logfile"}` prints the pending line with `command dir_` + `i`, which is the last value used on `mkdir`.

It returns:

```
$ awk 'NR%3 == 1 {print "mkdir dir_"++i} {print "mv", $1, "dir_"i} NR%3==0{print "echo \"command -o option tralla.lalla /path/dir_"NR/3"\" >> logfile"} END{print "echo \"command -o option tralla.lalla /path/dir_"i"\" >> logfile"}' a
mkdir dir_1
mv f1 dir_1
mv f2 dir_1
mv f3 dir_1
echo "command -o option tralla.lalla /path/dir_1" >> logfile
mkdir dir_2
mv f4 dir_2
mv f5 dir_2
mv f6 dir_2
echo "command -o option tralla.lalla /path/dir_2" >> logfile
mkdir dir_3
mv f7 dir_3
mv f8 dir_3
mv f9 dir_3
echo "command -o option tralla.lalla /path/dir_3" >> logfile
mkdir dir_4
mv f10 dir_4
echo "command -o option tralla.lalla /path/dir_4" >> logfile
```

Note that if the number of lines is a multiple of 3 (or `n` for the general case), the last line will be written twice. For that, the `END` block can be improved to:

```
END{ if (NR%n) { print ...  }}
```

So that it will just print if `NR` is not a multiple of `n`.

Comment: actually the command itself contains the directory name. ` echo "command -o option tralla.lala /path/$directoryname" > log ` everything from echo to log . How can I get that –

Comment: What do you mean? Try to explain properly and update your question with good sample input and understandable output.

Comment: sure TY . I am doing that now in a min

Comment: Mmmm with `echo "command -o option tralla.lalla /path/dir_1" >> logfile`, what do you mean? To print that code or to execute it?

Comment: Just print that  line echo "command -option tralla.lalla /path/dir_1" >> logfile like in above e.g. THis will generate a script. Not execute it. I will then execute it separately afterwards. I will update the posting again

Comment: You might want to show the scenario where you populate the `N` variable with `-v`.

Comment: Good point, @glennjackman . Just updated with an overview. Thanks one more time.

Comment: Thank you, folks, you rock. I just love your AWK-wardness.

Comment: thanks using the -v hint . This is the final command that worked. Yep you were right about n being var `  awk -v n=$nn 'NR%n == 1 {print "mkdir dir_"++i}  {print "mv", $1, "dir_"i} NR%n==0{print "echo \"command -o option tralla.lalla /path/dir_"NR/n "\" >> logfile" } END{print "echo \"command -o option tralla.lalla /path/dir_"i"\" >> logfile"}' file`

Comment: if the file has exact multiple 3 lines, the command will export two `echo` in the last.

Comment: Yes, @BMW, for that case a condition in `END{}` can be added. Something like `END{ if (NR%n) { print ...  }}`.

Comment: @BMW And the downvote was because... ? It is a bit annoying your inclination to downvote without specific reasons.

Comment: Since this is the accept answer, should be the correct one, which it is not currently, until you fix it.

Comment: @BMW and what if you check the answer before downvoting? Because if you had done that, you would have noticed that it was edited.

Comment: oh, it is too late, locked. will give you a upvote in other answer later.